# Failed to remove a CKReference from a CKReferenceList using CKRecord removeObject

Tags: ios, objective-c, cloudkit

I have a CKReferenceList for a list of employee, something may look like this

```
 (
    "<CKReference: 0xa5bc930; 83a97165-2635-4bda-a7eb-fabf5a725bed:(_defaultZone:__defaultOwner__)>",
    "<CKReference: 0xa50a2e0; 9B7F4269-D8BA-4CE9-9BCF-AD2047B73EB5:(_defaultZone:__defaultOwner__)>"
)
```

Then I have a another CKReference which points to a employee record. Which might look like this

```
"<CKReference: 0xa5bc330; 83a97165-2635-4bda-a7eb-fabf5a725bed:(_defaultZone:__defaultOwner__)>"
```

Notice that the reference of this specific employee is in the employee list, they have the same reference name, namely " 83a97165-2635-4bda-a7eb-fabf5a725bed".

When I tried to remove using the code below

```
 NSMutableArray<CKReference*>* employeeList = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithArray:self.employeeList];
    if(employeeList != nil){
        [employeeList removeObject:employeeReference];
    }
```

This won't remove the reference from the list even though the reference name is equal(the same happens to `contain` method).

I think the the `removeObject` uses the  `isEqual: method` as a criteria, so when comparing two CKReference, they are actually comparing the address, but not based on the string name.

Should I just overwrite the `isEqual` implementation to provide my own in order to remove a given CKReference from a list of CKReference.

Or is there any alternative approach for this?

Answer (score 0):

You can call `indexOfObjectPassingTest:` and compare whatever you need:

```
NSMutableArray <CKReference*>* employeeList = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

NSUInteger index = [employeeList indexOfObjectPassingTest:^BOOL(CKReference * _Nonnull obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL * _Nonnull stop) {
    return [obj.recordID.recordName isEqualToString:recordNameToRemove];
}];

if (index != NSNotFound) {
    [employeeList removeObjectAtIndex:index];
}
```